# Explain the difference between Turing Complete and Turing Equivalence

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, computability, programming-languages, turing-completeness

I'm not sure if I understand the difference between Turing Complete and Turing Equivalent programming languages.

> A computational system that can compute every Turing-computable
> function is called Turing-complete (or Turing-powerful).
>
> A Turing-complete system is called Turing-equivalent if every function
> it can compute is also Turing-computable; i.e., it computes precisely
> the same class of functions as do Turing machines.

I'm not sure if I understand the difference between these two terminologies properly and what "Turing-computable" means. So for example if I have a programming language $X$, it is Turing complete if it can do any and everything that a Turing Machine can do? And it $X$ ends up being Turing complete and it can be shown that all of the functions that it computes are Turing computable, then $X$ is also Turing equivalent?

Comment: There exist functions that can't be computed by TM. You can imagine some computational system that can magically compute more functions (e.g. [Oracle machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine)). This system won't be Turing-equivalent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A system is Turing-complete if it is at least as powerful as Turing machines.

A system is Turing-equivalent if it is exactly as powerful as Turing machines.

An example of a Turing-complete system which is not Turing equivalent is Turing machines with oracle access to an oracle for the halting problem.

One can come up with one additional definition to complete the picture: a system is *effective* if it is at most as powerful as Turing machines, that is, if every function computed by the system is computable by a Turing machine.