# If a Turing machine can compute any computable problem how can Turing completeness be achived?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, turing-completeness

To my knowledge a Turing machine is able to compute anything considered computable.

I got the definition of Turing completeness from this answer [Explain the difference between Turing Complete and Turing Equivalence](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/134273/explain-the-difference-between-turing-complete-and-turing-equivalence/134286#134286?newreg=1f531fb2e7f941b9b3d788aad0a8ea5a)

If so, how can one achieve Turing completeness?
Why is the Turing machine (a machine that can compute anything computable) not be able to compute what a Turing complete, but not Turing equivalent, system can?

Comment: @D.W. I edited it, let me know if you still have any doubts

Comment: Thank you for the edit.  What do you mean by "how can one achieve Turing completeness?"   What do you think a Turing machine is not able to compute what a Turing complete system can?

Comment: @D.W. I don't know, but from what is stated in the linked answer it's possible to have a system which has functions that cannot be implemented with a Turing machine, what kind of functions are these, I have no idea, and it's one of my doubts

Comment: One of the most famous functions that cannot be implemented with a Turing Machine is the *Halting Function* **H(M, i)** = 1 if Turing Machine **M** halts with input **i**, 0 otherwise.